# ¿Como forzar actualización de cache o como funciona la actualización de cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cache

Tengo una aplicación realizada con **ReactJs**, la cual contenía un `favicon` y algunas imágenes antiguas, las cuales actualice en mi proyecto.

Al realizar

```
npm run build
```

Y subir el proyecto, me doy cuenta que no actualiza `favicon` al igual que algunas imágenes, esto también sucede en ocasiones con los archivos `js`.

Actualizo archivos `js` y al subirlos a servidor, estos archivos no se actualizan en todos los navegadores.

Comment: `Ctrl + F5` en el navegador para refrescar la pagina y vaciar la cache.

Comment: @Riven Si eso de manera manual y lo realizamos del lado de desarrollo para pruebas, pero dicha acción no le puedo indicar a todo usuario que ingresa que la realice. y muchos de los usuarios no saben realizar dicha acción, por lo que es muy poco viable hacer las actualizaciones de esa manera.

Comment: Ohhh, entiendo... En ese caso hay un problema, y es que estar vaciando la caché del aplicativo tampoco es que sea muy buena idea... La cosa es que si vas a estar vaciando la caché, piensa en que si necesitas refrescar páginas en las que no sea necesario un login por ejemplo, no vas a saber cuándo deberías refrescar la página por una actualización, y en consecuencia vas a siempre estar vaciando la caché a fin de que tu usuario reciba las últimas actualizaciones en una página cacheada, en mi opinión yo dejaría que el usuario tenga esa versión hasta que reinicie el navegador.

Comment: O ya de últimas poner en las páginas que haz actualizado algo un script que te vacíe la caché y dejarlo con esa versión durante 1 o 2 días, a fin de dar tiempo a los usuarios de que abran tu página, luego vuelves a modificar la página y lo quitas hasta una nueva actualización, de esta forma te aseguras de que los usuarios tengan la versión más actualizada y al quitar el refresh de cache también aseguras que luego el caché funcione correctamente y la carga de la página se agilice

Comment: @Riven Estaré viendo si con que reinicien el navegador es suficiente, por que como ya lo dices, vaciar la cache constantemente no lo veo muy viable o recomendado, lo único que me interesa es que los usuarios puedan tener los cambios que se realizan en cada actualización, sin importar si son funciones de javaScript o cambios visuales.